# 'n new items in your Stack Exchange inbox' with a broken link

Tags: bug

I just got an email, that someone answered my question.

[image: Broken link]

In this answer, there is a link, which gets truncated. The problem is, that the link text gets truncated as well as the link. So it links to stackoverflow.c, which does not exist. Like this:

> After reading these answers and reading this answer to a related question (http://stackoverflow.c...

HTML source of the email:

```
<span style="color: #AAA;">answer:</span> After reading these
answers and reading this answer to a related question (http://stackoverflow.c...
```

Seems like my email client highlights this as a link incorrectly. So it's questionable if this is really a bug in StackOverflow.

Comment: I'd call that more "unfortunate" than "a problem". Though I wonder what made the link, the email generator or the client view.

Comment: The client view, see my edit.

Comment: So then no, it's not a problem with stack overflow. Your email client just saw what it thought was a link. CAVE JOHNSON, WE'RE DONE HERE.

Comment: @gunr2171: I suppose that SE could work around it by turning the URL into an actual (working) link, though. After all, the Markdown parser already does that.